# Get photo from post using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I am attempting to display the latest post from a public Facebook page on a website using the graph API.

Using the following URL, I am able to get the latest posts data:

https://graph.facebook.com/MYPAGENAME/posts?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

Which returns:

```
 {
   "data": [
            {
             "story": "MYPAGENAME added a new photo.",
             "created_time": "2017-08-20T19:00:00+0000",
             "id": "MYID"
            }

      ...
```

The post in question displays on the Facebook page with a photo included, but there is not 'photo' object (or anything similar) returned in the API data. How do I access the picture URL for this post? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `full_picture` field usually contains a larger version of the image used. You have to _ask_ for the field, of course, as you generally need to do since API v2.4; if that doesn’t mean anything to you, then go read the docs chapter on basic API usage first.

Comment: also, if you only want to get the latest post, use the limit parameter

Comment: Thanks @CBroe and luschn - I ended up using '...?fields=full_picture...'. Marked CoGe's answer right as it's correct, just not best for my particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This request will fetch posts and the media information for the first image for each post.

```
/posts?fields=attachments{media}?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Sometimes posts contain *multiple* images. If you'd like to support that you need to fetch the `subattachments` also:

```
/posts?fields=attachments{subattachments{media}}?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Note that this method usually only provides image URLs that are up to 720px wide. If you want higher resolution imagery, you need to access `data[0].attachments.data[0].subattachments.data[0].target.id` to get the actual image ID which you can then use to perform an additional query `/IMAGE_ID_HERE?fields=images` to obtain the higher resolution image. Increment the numbers to get additional posts and images inside each post.